# 'An unexpected error has occurred' when trying to view/modify Document Library?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, web-part, document-library, error, asset-library

I'm a relative beginner at using SharePoint Foundation 2010.

When I try to view or modify 'Documents' or 'Assets' libraries, an unexpected error occurs:

[image]

And when I try to insert either of these libraries into any of my web pages, I get the following error:

[image]

But I can view all the files saved in the libraries in SharePoint Designer, and up until a few days ago, the libraries were working just fine.

I've tried to create a new list or library but I also get the 'An unexpected error has occurred' message.

And, although perhaps unrelated, I also get the same error when trying to create a new Site or Workspace.

As far as I'm aware, I have full control of the site.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
After making no changes to the site since I posted this issue, when I loaded up SharePoint today I found that I can no longer access any of the pages/sites (apart from than the home page). All I get is the 'an unexpected error occurred' message. What is going on here?

Comment: did you seen any errors any uls logs in webfront end server or event viewer errors related sharepoint?

Comment: Where would I find those?

Answer (score 1):

Run following command in SharePoint Management Shell

> Replace your correlation id  get-splogevent -starttime
>   (get-date).addminutes(-20) | where-object { $_.correlation -eq
>   "correlation id" } | fl message > c:\errors.txt

Open local(C:) drive and check in errors file. You can get actaul error.